# Extract unique code and uid from log file using bash script

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm new to bash scripting and want to extract code and uid (unique) from log file into new csv file for further processing.

The file contains:

```
2021-02-16T10:13:54.629Z,app,"Code: 01-87-04 & Diff [{:uid=>""asdf1234"", :sid=>636614}] / [{:uid=>""asdf1234"", :sid=>0}]"
2021-02-16T10:11:22.914Z,app,"Code: 01-33-05 & Diff: [{:uid=>""kx4oa3hv"", :sid=>644448}, {:uid=>""v7jfxsum"", :sid=>643063}] / [{:uid=>""kx4oa3hv"", :sid=>0}, {:uid=>""v7jfxsum"", :sid=>0}]"
```

The desired output:

```
01-87-04, asdf1234
01-33-05, kx4oa3hv
01-33-05, v7jfxsum
```

I started with this script and blocked on extracting the multiple uids. Any help is appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "----->Loading file"
filename="some.csv"
while read -r line; do
  scene_id=`echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}'`

  echo $scene_id
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: You should copy/paste that script into http://shellcheck.net and fix what it tells you about. Also see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for other issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any awk and sort in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -v OFS=', ' '{n=split($0,uids,/""/); for (i=2;i<n;i+=2) print $2, uids[i]}' file | sort -u
01-33-05, kx4oa3hv
01-33-05, v7jfxsum
01-87-04, asdf1234
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lne '%seen = (); ( $code ) = /Code:\s+(\S+)/; @uids = grep { !$seen{$_}++ } /uid\W+(\w+)/g; print join ",", $code, $_ for @uids;' in_file > out_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default and not printing it by default (contrast with `-p`).
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

`( $code ) = /Code:\s+(\S+)/;` : Extract the code.
`@uids = grep { !$seen{$_}++ } /uid\W+(\w+)/g;` : Extract uids, make unique.
`print join ",", $code, $_ for @uids;` : Print code and unique uids, 1 uid per line, in csv format.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: This only produces one of the two unique `uid` values on the second line of data, where the code is `01-33-05`.  The line has 4 occurrences of `uid`, but only 2 unique values.  The answer is otherwise excellent.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for the comment and the edit. Fixed the bug, updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed '
    s/[^ ]* //
    s/ /, /
    :a
    /:uid=>""/!d
    s//\
/
    s/ .*\n/ /
    s/"",/\
/
    P
    s/ .*\n/ /
    ba' file | sort -u
```

---

Or, in plain `bash` :

```
#!/bin/bash

ldc='"Code: '  # left delimiter for code
rdc=' '        # right delimiter for code
ldu=':uid=>""' # left delimiter for uid
rdu='"",'      # right delimiter for uid

declare -A seen

while read -r line; do
    [[ $line = *"$ldc"*"$rdc"* ]] || continue
    code=${line#*"$ldc"}
    code=${code%%"$rdc"*}
    while [[ $line = *"$ldu"*"$rdu"* ]]; do
        line=${line#*"$ldu"}
        code_uid="$code, ${line%%"$rdu"*}"
        if [[ ! ${seen[$code_uid]} ]]; then
            seen[$code_uid]=1
            printf '%s\n' "$code_uid"
        fi
    done
done < file
```

Given the input sample in the question, this  prints out the desired output exactly:

```
01-87-04, asdf1234
01-33-05, kx4oa3hv
01-33-05, v7jfxsum
```